# How to find the change of temperature in a inelastic collision?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, momentum, temperature, collision

I've found a very intricate task, that I have found no answer for on the internet:

> A meteorite (`m = 75000kg, velocity = 13000km/h,   c = 800J/(kgK)`) crashes into an asteroid (`m = 600000kg, velocity = 0km/h, c = 230J/(kg/K)`). The crash is inelastic. How much do they heat up, if their temperatures before crash are the same?

Because the crash is inelastic, the sum of the momenta before the crash equals the momentum of the conjoined bodies after the crash:

$$G_1 + G_2 = G \longrightarrow m_1v_1 + m_2v_2 = m_3v_3$$

Having calculated $v_3$ (velocity of conjoined bodies after the crash), we can now find the kinetic energy of the meteorite before the crash and subtract the kinetic energy of the conjoined bodies after the crash to find out how much heat was converted from kinetic heat to internal heat.

**Now, given the specific heat of both celestial bodies ($c_1$, $c_2$), I am interested how I can calculate the final temperature of the conjoined body after the crash.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Having calculated v3 (velocity of conjoined bodies after the crash),
> we can now find the kinetic energy of the metorite before the crash
> and subtract kinetic energy of conjoined bodies after the crash to
> find out how many heat was converted from kinetic heat to internal
> heat.

Strictly thermodynamically speaking, the lost macroscopic kinetic energy of the two objects is not "converted to heat". Heat is energy transfer due solely to temperature difference. It is converted to an increase in the microscopic internal energy of the atoms and molecules of the bodies.

> Now, given the specific heat of both celestial bodies (c1, c2), I am
> interested how I can calculate the final temperature of the conjoined
> body after the crash.

Unless you know the initial temperatures of the bodies before the collision, I don't believe you can determine the final temperature of the conjoined body after the crash. But you can determine the increase in temperature of the conjoined bodies, $\Delta T$, with the following assumptions:

(1) the two bodies were at the same temperature before the collision,

(2) the two conjoined bodies come to thermal equilibrium following the collision (have the same final temperature), and

(3) the conjoined bodies do not lose any energy by thermal radiation into space

Then the increase in temperature $\Delta T$ of the conjoined objects  can be calculated from the lost macroscopic kinetic energy $KE_{lost}$ using the masses and specific heats of the two objects.

I leave it to you to do the calculation as we are not to provide complete solutions to H&E problems, just guidance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, it did help indeed!

Comment: You are very welcome